# Using Administrative Tools on non-domain computer to manage domain servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7

Is it possible to get Administrative Tools on Windows 7 (not joined to domain) to administer servers that are domain joined (since they don't ask you to provide domain/login/pass)? If yes how can I force consoles to behave like I want to?

Comment: How did you run this? was this added in the target of the properties?

Comment: I just run `cmd` and that's it. I typed in right command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question. After a bit of testing this seems to do trick just fine:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>runas /netonly /user:<domain>\<username> "%SystemRoot%\system32\m mc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\dnsmgmt.msc /s" 
Enter the password for <domain>\<user>: 
Attempting to start C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe C:\Windows\system32\dnsmgmt.msc /s as user "<domain>\<user>" ...
```

---

The names of other snap-ins (to replace `dnsmgmt`) can be found easily in the shortcuts located at `%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools` in default installations of Windows 7.

---

Unfortunately this does not work for the Group Policy management snap-in (`gpmc.msc`), as Martin Binder explains [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/05f5548d-be01-4980-af04-585b0074f52a/rsat-tools-from-off-the-domain):

> ADUC only requires LDAP to work properly. GPMC in addition requires
>   \domain\sysvol and WMI access - and the latter two probably will not
>   work on your workstation. At least WMI will fail for sure because it
>   doesn't know much about foreign prinicpals :)

The workaround suggested in the thread is to use a virtual machine which is joined to the domain.